# How does React Redux handle successive changes in a loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, redux, render

If I have a loop that dispatches a redux action on each cycle, how do React and Redux handle updating connected components? If each redux action would individually cause a reRender of certain components, and assuming each cycle updates the state to have new values, do those components reRender each time around the loop?

Do a component's update lifecycle hooks run synchronously in the loop, or do React / Redux batch the expected changes somewhere and then update once after the loop has finished?

Based on my experience just now, it appears there is some kind of batching going on, because a component seems to be updating only at the end of the loop with all of the changes registering at once.

Any ideas on how to get around this? Meaning I want a connected component's "componentWillReceiveProps" method to run each time a redux action makes its way through the reducers and changes the state.

Comment: It should call componentWillReceiveProps every cycle. Every time you dispatch an action it updates the store, that should propagate to all the subscribed components and your component should receive new props. Could post some code?

Comment: i know setState is async, not sure about redux. but when you think about it, js works in  away that your loop will always finish before you will have a chance to deal with the results (this is why we have closures)

Comment: run loop with setInterval, keeping some arbitrary interval time. callback should increment counter and setState/dispatch-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear that React updates are asynchronous and, at least for changes caused by updating redux stores, changes are batched. It would be interesting to see what would happen with a loop running setState for that component. Regardless, the solution was to make the loop asynchronous such as the following (suggestions on clearer / more efficient ways to make an async loop would be appreciated):

```
const iterable = [...]

const asyncLoop = (i) => {
  if(!iterable[i]) return
  const cycle = new Promise (resolve=>{
      dispatchReduxAction(iterable[i])
      resolve(i+1)
  })
  cycle.then((j)=>{
    asyncLoop(j)
  })
}

asyncLoop(0)
```

Comment: Im curious how a generator loop will be treated in this case (like redux-saga)

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't sure about `redux` at first so i wrote my thoughts as a comment.
The more i thought about it the more i realize that we know the answer:
First of all, react's `setState` is async that's on thier [DOCS](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> This form of setState() is also asynchronous, and multiple calls
>   during the same cycle may be batched together.

But when you think about it, how can it not be?
Js has only 1 thread, this thread is so busy with your loop so it can't free it self to invoke the code like `dispatch` or `setState` etc.
When your loop is done, this is the time for all the "disptaching" and state settings to run, the amazing part here is that it can "remember" the context and scope of each variable and object, thanks to our good friend the closure.

Comment: What is interesting is, if you know redux, redux appears to be synchronous. When I followed my code step by step from each cycle of the loop, it would dispatch the redux action and that action would flow all the way through the reducers and the store changes got to the "mapStateToProps" function of the connected component. This would all happen before the next iteration of the loop. Its just once the new data generated by the change in the redux store got to the component, the component wouldn't change. So Redux appears to be synchronous, and as you said, React updates are async and batched.

Comment: I think redux-saga can help here as its implementing generators

Comment: @LeoFabrikant If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

Just for answer sake, else, above answer is right.
Run loop with a callback in setInterval, keeping some arbitrary interval time. The callback should increment the counter of loop and setState/dispatch-action